# How to make a new List when you see a "(" and close it using ")". Lisp to Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, lisp, interpreter

I want to make a Lisp interpreter and I am just struggling on translating it after tokenizing it. So after Tokenizing it the list I have looks something like this.

```
tokenized = ["(", "car", "'","(", "20", "40", "60", ")", ")"]
```

What I want is to Translate it in to something that looks like this

```
translated = [["CAR", "'", [20, 40, 60]]]
```

I need to a way to make a new list when it sees "(" and closes it when it sees ")". Let me know if I need to explain it better, I am terrible at explaining.

Comment: That sounds like a recursive descent parser.

Comment: I have thought about recursion I just have no idea how to put it in code.

Comment: I also have unittests if that would help draw up a better idea of what I need.

Comment: As a note, this is *not* how Lisp readers work in general: there's no separate tokenization step.  It's worth reading the description of how they *do* work (for instance the Common Lisp reader) to understand why they work the way they do.

Comment: @ignisvolens not every lisp has [read macros](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node188.html). Without them, why *not* have the separate tokenization step?

Comment: @WillNess: that's true.  I personally see no purpose in a lisp which makes implementing extensions to itself unduly hard like that – it's like not having macros – but they do exist, obviously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so this works like a recursive descent parser. Every time it sees an open bracket, it creates a new `list`, appends that to the output list and recurses down, but with the new list. Every time it sees a close bracket, it just returns to where it was before. The base case to recursion is reaching the end of the items to parse:

```py
def rdp(items):
    it = iter(items)
    def inner(it, out):
        while True:
            token = next(it)
            if token == '(':
                nxt = []
                out.append(nxt)
                inner(it, nxt)
                continue
            elif token == ')':
                return
            out.append(token)

    nxt = []
    try:
        inner(it, nxt)
    except StopIteration:
        pass
    return nxt

tokenized = ["(", "car", "'","(", "20", "40", "60", ")", ")"]
translated = rdp(tokenized)
```

Output as requested

**Note:** I've just edited it to move the `try:except:` outside of the `inner()` recursive function to avoid repeated exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you an answer in Lisp (where I assume strict left to right sequential evaluation):

```
(define (relist tokens)
  (let ((tok #f))
    (define (get)
      (set! tok (car tokens))
      (set! tokens (cdr tokens))
      tok)
    (define (go)
      (cond
        ((null? tokens)
          '())     ; we're done
        ((eq? (get) ")")
          '())     ; done with this level
        ((eq? tok "(")
          (cons (go)     ; get the nested list
                (go)))   ;  then continue
        (else 
          (cons tok      ; go on filling
                (go))))) ;  this list
    (go)))

;; testing in DrRacket:

(relist '[1 2 "(" 3 "(" 4 ")" ")" 5]) ;=> '(1 2 (3 (4)) 5)
(relist '[1 2 "(" 3 "(" 4 ")"     5]) ;=> '(1 2 (3 (4) 5))
```

The variable `tok` is local to the function. Its scope here includes all the internal function definitions as well as the function's body.

All the invocations of `go` work with and advance along the same input stream (list), `tokens`, by calling `get`.

When the signal to open up a new sublist, the token `"("`, is received, we do so with the recursive, non-tail invocation of `go` (ignoring the token itself of course).

Otherwise we just use the received token and continue, which is expressed as the tail invocation of `go` (both of them, in both cases). You will naturally express this with other means, native to Python. I just wanted to show you the essential minimal structure of this, nicely seen in Lisp.